# Coco2d animation delay for first time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In coco2d - When i have animate the first time there is a small delay,but animate in second time,it will works perfect(no delay),How to overcome this problem

my code is below

-(void)animateImages:(NSString *)animationName startImageName:(NSString*)sImage  individualImageName:(NSString *)imgName withDelay:(CGFloat)delay startFrame:(NSInteger)sFrame endFrame:(NSInteger)eFrame 
{
    isAnimating=YES;

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",animationName]];        

CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",animationName]];

[self addChild:spriteSheet z:0];

// Load up the frames of our animation
NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = sFrame; i <= eFrame; i=i+2) {
    [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d.jpg",imgName,i]]];//@"stand march %d.jpg"
}


NSLog(@"After NSMutableArray");


CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:delay];

CCAction *standByAtion =[CCSequence actions:                          
                         [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO] times:1],[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setAnimatingToFalseAfterAnimation:)],nil];


 [walkAnimFrames removeAllObjects];
 walkAnimFrames=nil;

CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CCSprite *images = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sImage]];//@"stand march 101.jpg"

images.position=ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
images.scaleX=1.6;
images.scaleY=1.59;

[spriteSheet addChild:images];
[images runAction:standByAtion];

NSString *audioName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Jump.caf"];
[self playSoundEffectNamed:audioName];
```

}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then you whant to set different delay between frames in single animation. If you want, when you need just repeat frames 2 or more times. For example:
you have an animation with 3 frames: 1st must bu shown for 1 second, 2nd - for 2 second, and 3rd - for 0.5 second. To do so, make an animation with delay 0.5seconds, add there TWO 1st frames, FOUR 2nd frames and ONE 3rd frame. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The delay at first call is because of the loading of the images.

The first time you call this it really loads the images. This is slow.
Second time it does not load them from disk but reads the already loaded images from a cache. This is fast. Solution: Load all images for the animation once before you call this.

Comment: In the init method i have use the below code         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"March.plist"];        
        [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"March.png"]]; but also it tooks few seconds to load at first time

Comment: Are you using the simulator? Have you checked if this also happens on the device ?

Comment: Also: Have you identified what part of the code is causing the delay ? Is it definately the loading of these images ? If it is the images - did you check if your pre-loading is working as you expect ? Are you really loading exactly the same images in the init methods ?

Comment: My problem is solved, I have loded all spritsheets in memory -in init method, Thanks

Comment: Shall i add u in my contact-gmail, I am a new iPhone programmer.Thanks